# how to accommodate mobile devices

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, mobile

I have built a site that is fully functional on PC, Laptop and Ipad devices. I want to expand it to take on mobile phones. The problem i have faced is i am not sure the best way to do this. I currently Use themes in my site. I would think the best way to do this would be to detect the device and change the theme based on if it is a phone or a PC. A lot of the examples i found show how to do this when you are linking Style sheets.

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)"
    href="800.css" />`

Should i be doing this through linked stylesheets or can i do this with a theme somehow?

Comment: You're on the right track with the above. Here's a good starting point for research: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Unfortunately, you're doing it the hard way by adding mobile support last. For your next project I would highly recommend the [mobile first responsive design](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/mobile-first-responsive-web-design/) approach.

Comment: Good question, I will be working on it after 1 week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the `Desktop + Mobile` themes work like following code. The best way is using `@media` queries ([check this link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [this one](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)). Instead of using more stylesheets, use only one.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 801px) {
    /* Your style here */
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    /* Your style here for mobile  */
}
```